# Recyclerview onBindViewHolder is called for all item in NestedScrollview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a verticle **recyclerview** inside **NestedScrollView**. And because of That **onbindviewItem()** is called for all items due to which the app crashes. Removing Scrollview fixed the problem, but it changes the Scrolling behavior of the App. Any Ideas? What should be done?

Comment: you can try recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); why do you need the nestedScrollView ?

Comment: I did that too. But it doesn't work.  There are some other UI elements on the top buttons, textviews etc.

Comment: Edit your question and paste the XML for the `RecyclerView` declaration from your layout XML file.